# Change camera resolution with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, usb, webcam

I am trying to set the resolution of a USB camera to 1280x720 via OpenCV using the code below:

```
VideoCapture Camera(0);
Camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,(unsigned int)1280);
Camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,(unsigned int)720);

while(1){
   Mat f;
   Camera.read(f);
   imshow("test cam", f);
   waitKey(10);
   cout<<f.size().width<<"x"<<f.size().height<<endl;
}
```

However the resolution is limited to 640x480. I say limited as setting the resolution lower to 320x240 does work, so I assume there could be driver/hardware limitation somewhere. I am not familier with the Pi to work it out. I can confirm the camera is capable of outputting 1280x720 and even 1920x1080 images via "fswebcam".

Comment: Might need to tell the camera to use MJPEG (via `CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC`, looks like), *especially* if it's a USB2 device.  Also, what does `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` return?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added the line ```Camera.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC,0x47504A4D); ``` and it works fine. I can even stream two cameras at 1280x720.

Comment: Does camera specifications include the other resolution options? If yes, then you can be able to change it